# Searching the Scala documentation for #::

Tags: scala, search, scaladoc

I am trying to find the documentation for the Scala operator method `#::`. I believe that it is defined in the `Stream` class because of an [example](http://voidmainargs.blogspot.com/2010/12/lazy-sieve-eratosthenes-in-scala-and.html) I found that uses it.

My question is not particular to this method (although I would like to know where the docs are), but how to search the Scala docs in general. I tried entering `#::` in the search box in the upper left of the documentation page (2.8.1), but found nothing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest using the [Reference Index](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index/index-%23.html) - it's designed specifically to look for any kind of symbol (class, traits, methods, vals, vars) regardless of it's hierarchical position - contrasting with the Scaladoc's left index which doesn't show inner classes, traits or objects.

Unfortunately it's only available in the nightly. You can see the whole thing at [nightly Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html). Notice the upper box in the left frame, above the index.

Hope it will be bundled with Scala 2.9.0.

**Edit** As of 2.9.0, the reference index started to be bundle with [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#package). No need to go to the nightly docs now.

Comment: @pedrofurla only suggestion I could make is that they start using the same feature (an alphabet to select from at the top of the sidebar) in the stable docs as well.

Comment: @pedrofurla: a couple of possible improvements to vscaladoc: 1) show inner classes in the sidebar. 2) in each class, add a list of methods that can be called as though they were class members, based on implicit conversions. Be sure to show which class or conversion is required to get that method, and make sure it's capable enough to detect the `ConsWrapper` conversion which is a bit unusual becuase it's a by-name conversion.

Comment: @pedrofurla: I thought vscaladoc was what you used these days to generate the standard library documentation. Whatever -- the standard library documentation should have these features.

Comment: @Ken, check the links provided in my answer for no. 1. For no. 2, this is a pretty hard to achieve goal, nevertheless very useful.

Comment: @pedrofurla: I don't see `Predef.<:<` in the side bar.

Answer (score 12):

As others have already mentioned, `#::` is defined on [`scala.collection.immutable.Stream.ConsWrapper`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream%24%24ConsWrapper.html). I just wanted to take a minute to elaborate on why that is.

In general, to call an operator on an object, that object needs to exist. However, the idea with a Stream is the tail of the stream is not evaluated until it needs to be. So consider the following stream:

```
def fibs(a:Int,b:Int):Stream[Int] = a #:: fibs(b,a+b)
```

Ordinarily, we would need to evaluate the recursive `fibs` call so that we could call the `#::` operator on it. This would lead to runaway recursion. This is *NOT* what we want. What we want is for the reciever to be a by-name `Stream`. Hence the `ConsWrapper`:

The constructor for `ConsWrapper` is `class ConsWrapper[T](tail: => Stream[T])` taking a by-name `Stream`, and it's created through an implicit conversion `Stream.consWrapper[T](stream: => Stream[T])`, which also takes a by-name `Stream`.

Hence, we have performed an implicit conversion on the result of a function that has not yet been called, and we have mimiced the effect of calling `#::` with a by-name `this` reference.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the scaladoc search does not allow you to look for an inner class/object (i.e. whose parent is not a package). The declaration of `#::` is either `Stream.#::` or `Stream.ConsWrapper.#::`:

```
object Stream { 
  //STUFF
  /** An extractor that allows to pattern match streams with `#::`.
   */
  object #:: {
    def unapply[A](xs: Stream[A]): Option[(A, Stream[A])] = 
      if (xs.isEmpty) None
      else Some((xs.head, xs.tail))
  }
  class ConsWrapper[A](tl: => Stream[A]) {
    def #::(hd: A): Stream[A] = new Stream.Cons(hd, tl)
    def #:::(prefix: Stream[A]): Stream[A] = prefix append tl
  }
  //MORE STUFF
}
```

You could request this as an RFE to the scaladoc tool in [trac](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala).

In IntelliJ IDEA's scala plugin, you could have used **symbol lookup** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd>) and typed `#::` and this would have brought up both declarations of `#::` immediately.

Comment: Except that `Stream.#::` is wrong. The OP is asking about `Stream.ConsWrapper.#::`.

Comment: True - answer still valid, though

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm not sure which one (`Stream.#::` or `Stream.ConsWrapper.#::`) is executing. I'll need to study the code.

Comment: @Ralph: `Stream.#::` is an object used for pattern matching. It's not what's being called. You're calling `Stream.ConsWrapper.#::`, as I have explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That particular method is defined in a nested class inside of `Stream`, called [`scala.collection.immutable.Stream.ConsWrapper`](http://Scala-Lang.Org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$$ConsWrapper.html).

And no, I have absolutely no idea how one would go about finding it. I only stumbled across it by accident. And even though I *knew* where to find it now, when I wanted to post the link to the class here in my answer, I *still* couldn't find it on the first (and even second and third) try.

Answer (score 2):

Well, normally, if we see

```
foo bar baz
```

then bar is a method, defined for foo, so we first look in the class/object - definition of foo, then the inheritance/trait tree upwards (+ in implicit conversions to and from foo, in the current file, and in (directly) included files).

Except 'bar' ends in a colon, which is the case here. Then it is to be read in reverse order -

```
foo bar: baz
```

is not

```
foo.bar: (baz)
```

, but

```
baz.bar: (foo)
```

So we have to look up in the way described above, but not for foo, but for baz.