# tail recursion fails (possibly because of implicit cons conversion)

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, tail-recursion

I have what I believe to be a fairly simple tail-recursive function. However, `@tailrec` tells me otherwise.

```
  @tailrec
  def _next(continue : String, current : List[Long], first : Boolean ) : Stream[Long]  = {
    current match {
      case head :: tail => head #:: _next(continue, tail, false) //this line breaks tailrec
      case Nil if first => empty
      case _ => {
        val (nc, nl) = getIds(continue)
        _next(nc, nl, true)
      }
    }
  }
```

which presents me with

```
[error] could not optimize @tailrec annotated method _next: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
[error]  case head :: tail => head #:: _next(continue, tail, false)
[error]                                     ^
```

it probably has to do with the implicit notification I receive from eclipse: `- Implicit conversions found: _next(continue, tail, false) => consWrapper(_next(continue, tail, false))`, but unfortunately, that isn't helping me resolve the issue.

How can I fix this, and, for brownie points, where did I go wrong thinking this would tail-recurse?

Comment: you last operation is **appending**, not `_next` call -- use recursive accumulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the last operation in your code is not the call to `_next`, but the `Stream` cons operation `#::`.

One solution is to use a `StreamBuilder` to build your stream and keep this `StreamBuilder` as an accumulator variable.

```
  @tailrec
  def _next(continue : String, current : List[Long], first : Boolean, acc: Stream.StreamBuilder[Long]) : Stream[Long]  = {
    current match {
      case head :: tail =>
        acc += head
        _next(continue, tail, false, acc)
      case Nil if first => acc.result
      case _ => {
        val (nc, nl) = getIds(continue)
        _next(nc, nl, true, acc)
      }
    }
  }
```

This is not particularly efficient - the `StreamBuilder` is more appropriate if you add entire collections to it using the `++=` instead of `+=`. For this reason, consider changing your code to something like this:

```
  @tailrec
  def _next(continue : String, current : List[Long], first : Boolean, acc: Stream.StreamBuilder[Long]) : Stream[Long]  = {
    current match {
      case Nil =>
        acc.result
      case list =>
        acc += list
        val (nc, nl) = getIds(continue)
        _next(nc, nl, true, acc)
    }
  }
```

Comment: finding this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525449/tail-recursive-bounded-stream-of-pairs-of-integers-scala it seems that though it is not tail recursive, that is perfectly alright. Is it? Will this not run out of stack space for large sets?

Comment: they will be: I estimate tens of thousands of items. Could you explain what the difference between my situation and the one in the linked answer is?