# Aggregate Scala Stream multiple times with overlapping segments

Tags: scala, stream, aggregation

How can I make the following function tail recursive and fully streaming?

```
def aggregate[A, B](in: Stream[A], predicate: Stream[A] => B): Stream[B] = {
    in match {
        case Empty => Stream.empty
        case head #:: Empty => predicate(in) #:: Stream.empty
        case head #:: tail => predicate(in) #:: aggregate(tail, predicate)
    }
}
```

The goal process the stream with some lookahead. As an example let's say we have a stream of sequential numbers: `val s: Stream[Int] = Stream.from(0)`. Now I'd like to calculate the sum of 5 sequential elements of this stream beginning at every element. With the function above it would look like this: `val r: Stream[Int] = aggregate(s, _.take(5).sum)`, producing the stream of `10, 15, 20...`. But this will break the stack on large input. How can I optimize this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say this will break the stack on larger input? Have you tried this? Please refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525449/tail-recursive-bounded-stream-of-pairs-of-integers-scala), where Ken Bloom points out that streams don't need tail recursion.

In fact, I ran this on a take 1,000,000 and it returned in < 1 second.

Comment: Right you are right, I have to confess that I didn't try this code on large input because I was 100% sure that it will break the stack.