# What is the #:: operator in a scala Stream?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching the Scala documentation for #::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553909/searching-the-scala-documentation-for)

I'm looking through the docs of [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html)

The filter method has this code:

```
def naturalsFrom(i: Int): Stream[Int] = i #:: naturalsFrom(i + 1)
naturalsFrom(1)  10 } filter { _ % 5 == 0 } take 10 mkString(", ")
```

What is the #:: operator?  Does this map to a function call somewhere?

Answer (score 14):

As SHildebrandt says, #:: is the cons operator for Streams.

In other words, #:: is to streams what :: is to Lists

```
val x = Stream(1,2,3,4)                   //> x  : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
10#::x                                    //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(10, ?)

val y = List(1,2,3,4)                     //> y  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
10::y                                     //> res1: List[Int] = List(10, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
x #:: xs
```

returns

```
Stream.cons(x, xs)
```

which returns a Stream of an element x followed by a Stream xs.