# What is #:: method

Tags: scala

It might be a trivial question, but I am unable to find the documentation for it:

Inside `Stream`, and at other places I have seen examples using the method `#::`.  For example:

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }
```

But I dont find the documentation for implicit method `#::` in the [api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream). What is it? and where is it declared?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching the Scala documentation for #::](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553909/searching-the-scala-documentation-for)

Comment: protip: use [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/) to lookup symbols like this

Comment: oh, man. That is awesome, re: @om-nom-nom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First value member of in the [Stream.ConsWrapper](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream%24%24ConsWrapper). I found by using the symbol index on the left pane under the search box.

Here is its signature:

def #::(hd: A): Stream[A]

In few words is the List `::` but for streams.

Comment: But why is it hidden. It is so tough find it out

Comment: Hidden is a bit hard. The problem is that left box in Scaladoc only shows the first level children. For that exact reason I made the reference index. I don't understand why ppl don't use it!

Comment: Till now I assumed it to be starting character indexed search. Ideally, I would want Stream.consWrapper to be shown inside Stream api itself