# Why is it so difficult to browse through Scala api?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Firstly I had an issue finding `#::` method of Stream. Which got resolved from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162193/what-is-method).

Now I am looking for the below method in the `Stream`

```
 def iterate[A](start: A, len: Int)(f: A => A): Stream[A]
```

The [Stream API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) has no mention of it.

Secondly in the Scala Doc, why can't they have all the inner classes defined in the same respective parent class itself. Why does a user has to go and click at `c` character on left panel to search for [Stream.consWrapper](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$ConsWrapper) when he could directly read it inside the documentation for `Stream` itself?

Am I missing something? I am a Scala newbie (3 months), but if a new user can't get used to it, most of it will not be able to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`iterate` is not a method of the `Stream` class, but a method of the `Stream` object. It is described [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$).

From the scaladoc page for the `Stream` class that you linked, you can go directly to the scaladoc page for the `Stream` object by clicking on the "C" (for "class") icon at the top, and back by clicking on the "O" icon.

As for finding operators, you can click on "#" at the top of the left search panel, which brings you to [this page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#index.index-_) which lists all operators of the standard library.
There you can find mention of the `#::` operator and just ckick on it.

As for ConsWrapper, it is a member of the `Stream` object, not a member of the `Stream` class. And sure enough, you will find it mentioned on the scaladoc page for the `Stream` object, in the "Type members" section.